# AppendTo does not work as desired

Tags: jquery

When I say, `msg.appendTo(ele.parent().next())`, the msg successfully gets appended to a `<p> with class=foo`

How can I specify it explicitly in the statement?

I tried `msg.appendTo(ele.parent().next().find('.foo'));`

but it doesn't work

Comment: provide more details & your markup. Nobody here has a second sight.

Comment: yes sorry..but Felix Kling had a second sight!

Comment: Don't rely on that ;) I'm just in a good mood :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not totally clear, but maybe you are looking for [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
msg.appendTo(ele.parent().siblings('.foo'));
```

---

Explanation:

Your code `msg.appendTo(ele.parent().next())` will append `msg` to the next sibling of the parent element of `ele`.

Whereas `msg.appendTo(ele.parent().next().find('.foo'))` will append `msg` to all elements with class `foo` **inside** the next sibling of the parent element of `ele`.

---

Whenever you are uncertain about how a method works, read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) first. Most questions will be covered by it.

[Documentation of `.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Also you should probably read about how `.next()`, `.find()`, etc. work.

Comment: and can I use appendTo specifying the id of the element directly, without navigating?

Comment: @Gokul: Of course, you can do `msg.appendTo('#id');` Just read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and have a look at the examples. It is all very well explained.